# Ошибка при запуске Android resource linking failed

Tags: java, android, gradle

Программа работа исправно, все компилировалось. Решил открыть проект через месяц и выдает такие ошибки, не дает запустить приложение. Не понимаю в чем проблема, подскажите пожалуйста, что может быть за проблема.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml","position":{"startLine":2,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":55,"endColumn":93,"endOffset":144}}],"original":"ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:3:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_1000 not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml","position":{"startLine":3,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":149,"endColumn":93,"endOffset":238}}],"original":"ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:4:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_900 not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml","position":{"startLine":4,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":243,"endColumn":92,"endOffset":331}}],"original":"ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:5:5-93: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_0 not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml","position":{"startLine":5,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":336,"endColumn":93,"endOffset":425}}],"original":"ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:6:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_800 not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml","position":{"startLine":6,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":430,"endColumn":93,"endOffset":519}}],"original":"ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:7:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_700 not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml","position":{"startLine":7,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":524,"endColumn":93,"endOffset":613}}],"original":"ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:8:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_600 not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml","position":{"startLine":8,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":618,"endColumn":93,"endOffset":707}}],"original":"ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:9:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_500 not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml","position":{"startLine":9,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":712,"endColumn":93,"endOffset":801}}],"original":"ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:10:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_400 not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml","position":{"startLine":10,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":806,"endColumn":93,"endOffset":895}}],"original":"ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:11:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_300 not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml","position":{"startLine":11,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":900,"endColumn":93,"endOffset":989}}],"original":"ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:12:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_200 not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml","position":{"startLine":12,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":994,"endColumn":93,"endOffset":1083}}],"original":"ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:13:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_100 not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml","position":{"startLine":13,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":1088,"endColumn":92,"endOffset":1176}}],"original":"ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:14:5-93: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_50 not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml","position":{"startLine":14,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":1181,"endColumn":92,"endOffset":1269}}],"original":"ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:15:5-93: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_10 not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml","position":{"startLine":15,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":1274,"endColumn":101,"endOffset":1371}}],"original":"ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:16:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_1000 not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml","position":{"startLine":16,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":1376,"endColumn":101,"endOffset":1473}}],"original":"ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:17:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_900 not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml","position":{"startLine":17,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":1478,"endColumn":100,"endOffset":1574}}],"original":"ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:18:5-101: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_0 not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml","position":{"startLine":18,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":1579,"endColumn":101,"endOffset":1676}}],"original":"ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:19:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_800 not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml","position":{"startLine":19,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":1681,"endColumn":101,"endOffset":1778}}],"original":"ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:20:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_700 not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml","position":{"startLine":20,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":1783,"endColumn":101,"endOffset":1880}}],"original":"ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:21:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_600 not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml","position":{"startLine":21,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":1885,"endColumn":101,"endOffset":1982}}],"original":"ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:22:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_500 not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:3:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_1000 not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.


ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:3:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_1000 not found.
    
ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:4:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_900 not found.
    
ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:5:5-93: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_0 not found.
    
ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:6:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_800 not found.
    
ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:7:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_700 not found.
    
ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:8:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_600 not found.
    
ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:9:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_500 not found.
    
ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:10:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_400 not found.
    
ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:11:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_300 not found.
    
ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:12:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_200 not found.
    
ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:13:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_100 not found.
    
ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:14:5-93: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_50 not found.
    
ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:15:5-93: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_10 not found.
    
ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:16:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_1000 not found.
    
ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:17:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_900 not found.
    
ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:18:5-101: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_0 not found.
    
ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:19:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_800 not found.
    
ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:20:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_700 not found.
    
ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:21:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_600 not found.
    
ERROR:/Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e5160649d44c6889b4efb289ab4e5b7e/material-1.5.0-alpha03/res/values-v31/values-v31.xml:22:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_500 not found.
```

Comment: File->Invalidate cashes and restart

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov делал несколько раз – не помогает :(

Comment: попробовать поменять версию материала material-1.5.0 на alpha02 например

Comment: @Pentiux сработало, спасибо! Странно, конечно, что на третьей альфе такие ошибки

Comment: @СергейГуков можете теперь обратно поставить 03 поидее должно работать. У вас просто не было файлов из этого пакета, потому не собиралось

Comment: @Pentiux неа, на 03 опять ошибка появляется

Comment: @СергейГуков очень интересно, тогда либо на 02 сидите, пока не выйдет новая версия. Либо попробуйте удалить всю папку кэша из юзеров, /Users/gukov/.gradle/caches/ только это заденет и другие проекты, если есть.

Comment: @Pentiux я и папку уже пробовал удалять - все равно то же самое) придется пока на 02 сидеть

Comment: @СергейГуков а какой targetSdkVersion ?

Comment: @Pentiux targetSdkVersion 30 и compileSdkVersion 30

Comment: values-v31/values-v31.xml поставьте 31 версию. он почему-то пытается в ней найти, если я все верно понимаю.

Comment: @Pentiux да, отлично, спасибо, с 31 версией 03 нормально работает. Правда теперь еще требует для android 12 прописать в манифесте android:exported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из комментариев 2 решения:
1)с `targetSdkVersion 30` и `compileSdkVersion 30` откатить на `material-1.5.0-alpha02`
2)изменив на 31 работает и с `material-1.5.0-alpha03`

Answer (score 0):

я смог исправить проблему, добавив строку ниже в gradle.properties file.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык